# Asymptote produced from a composition of two polynomials and an arbitrary function.

Tags: calculus, polynomials, asymptotics

I am interested in any references and/or information regarding this sort of asymptotic relationship.

Given the composition:

$$\frac{f(x)h(x)+g(x)}{f(x)}$$

With the following polynomial functions $\ g(x)=\sum_{i=0}^ka_ix^i$ ,
 $\ f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^nb_ix^i$ and an arbitrary function $h(x)$.

Assuming that $\lim_{x\to \infty}h(x)$ exists and $\text{deg(f)}$ $\ge$ $\text{deg(g)}$ than.

$$\frac{f(x)h(x)+g(x)}{f(x)} \sim h(x)+\frac{a_k}{b_n}$$

Noting that $\frac{a_k}{b_n}=0$ when  $\text{deg(f)}$ $\gt$ $\text{deg(g)}$.

Comment: Is there anything in particular that you are looking for? It seems like you have a handle on its behaviour.

Comment: Yes, in particular i'm looking to find any sources that explore asymptotes in this generalized way. Every book, mostly differential calculus, and online source that I've seen only covers linear and sometimes quadratic horizontal asymptotes.